# Suggestion to handle Deadlock

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

There are like 6 procedures which are called internally to get data from a transactional table and do aggregations on the retrieved data , formated as an XML and then send emails hourly.

During this process, a lot of logging in done and logs are also sent as email in an HTML format(in the same email).There is one procedure where a deadlock occurs and one section of the email is always missed or we have a deadlock occurence(LOGS). So in order to handle I am trying to use the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT in that particular procedure. Can anyone please suggest how if this has worked for them or else which is the best way to handle this kind of deadlock.

Can I do a retry of that particular procedure internally by checking the output is Null or not.

#### I cant let the other process fail as that is a transaction.But I need the HTML to show all the information without missing anything in the body.

EDIT: This occurs very rarely.But the frequency is increasing daily now.I am not able to understand as the procedure is just trying to read from the transactional table and make some calculations and format it into XML and the other transaction is writting to the transactional table. So how does a WRITE effect a READ

Comment: removed SQL Server 2008/2012 tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the deadlock in order to resolve this.

A *deadlock* occurs when one process holds a resource that the other requires in order to proceed and vice-versa. You'll get a deadlock when you have two processes that acquire the same set of resources in different orders. For instance, If process P1 acquires resources in the following order:

1. Resource A
2. Resource B

And a competing process, P2, requires the same resources in a different order:

1. Resource B
2. Resource A

   - P1 starts and acquires exclusive access to Resource A.
   - P2 starts and acquires exclusive access to Resource B.

In order for each to continue, P1 needs access to Resource B and P2 needs access to Resource A.

Neither of them can acquire the resource they need, thus causing the deadlock.

This is different than blocking, where one process is simply waiting for another process to release the needed resource. Given sufficient time, the blocking will be resolved. In a deadlock, the blocking cannot be resolved.

The SQL Engine can (and does) detect the deadlock situation. It resolves it by selecting one process or the other as the deadlock victim and rolling back.

Fix the deadlock by identifying the problem and resolving it, not by simply retrying and hoping it goes through. SQL Trace may help you identify the problem. You may need a DBA to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler (less dangerous) approach would be to change the six procedures in question so that they do dirty reads (i.e., WITH(NOLOCK)).  This should work even in a deadlock, although you might get garbage data.

Comment: Hey Ash, Can you please ellaoborate on what kind of dirty reads/Garbage data am I looking at...